# accepts_nested_attributes_for: How to reject a record if its duplicated

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to reject if the record is duplicate here is the code.

```
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :member_im_messenger_names, allow_destroy: true  , reject_if: lambda {|attributes| puts attributes.inspect
 attributes['im_screen_name'].blank? or MemberImMessengerName.where('member_id=? AND im_screen_name=? AND im_messenger_name_id=?',self.id,attributes['im_screen_name'],attributes['im_messenger_name_id']).count>0 }
```

I am not able to get the current model id in this block of code. i have tried self.id and attributes[:id] but all in-vain.

Please suggest how can i get the id. as self.id returns null.

Comment: If `attributes[:id]` is missing, it means your form isn't submitting the ID. Can you show what your `params` look like when you submit the form? Or better, the form view itself?

Comment: basically self.id is not the fields_for attribute its of the model attribute in which accepts_nested_attributes_for is declared.

Comment: In the `reject_if` lambda, `self` is a model class rather than a model object. Attribute methods, including `id`, are only available on model objects. We'd need to see your parameters and your form to know more.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using the following:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :member_im_messenger_names, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :im_already_exists_or_empty    


def im_already_exists_or_empty(attributed)
   return true if attributed['im_screen_name'].blank? or MemberImMessengerName.where('member_id=? AND im_screen_name=? AND im_messenger_name_id=?',self.id,attributed['im_screen_name'],attributed['im_messenger_name_id']).count>0
   false
end
```